# Demarcate and populate multiple variables across multiple file types?

Tags: node.js, unix, npm

I'm building a CLI for a npm package generator, and I want to find/replace multiple variables in multiple formats across multiple files. This includes the content of those files as well (think, CSS, HTML, JS, Markdown, etc.)

There are potentially many combinations of ways of getting the necessary data as well.

In order of decreasing likelihood:

1. User input
2. Environment variables
3. Values present in `~/.npmrc` (not sure how to reference these anywhere)
4. External API calls based on 1. or 2.

How would you approach building something like this? 
I've looked at the source of [Yeoman generators](http://yeoman.io/authoring/), [Express's generator](https://github.com/expressjs/generator/), [`npm-init` modules](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#init-module), but I've never come something than can do file titles, content, and different sources.

I'm quite certain I'm overthinking it, but consider this post a sanity check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved a similar problem for an `npm` package generator we use at AdRoll for our UI component library, as written about [here](http://tech.adroll.com/blog/frontend/2015/11/12/rollup-react-and-npm-at-adroll.html#new-component-generator).

We use [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/authoring/) for our npm package / component generator. The generator consists of a set of boilerplate files we manipulate so that the `npm` package has the right file structure and content in it.

We use user input for the necessary data. The developer provides the name of the component which will be used to populate component-specific content and rename files as we need to.

Each boilerplate file is a Yeoman template file (see the "Copying a template file" section [here](http://yeoman.io/authoring/file-system.html)). We use placeholders in each file where the component name should go. In terms of renaming the file, you can specify a different `destinationPath` for the template file once it's processed.

So say we have a component template file called `ComponentName.jsx` that looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
let <%= componentName %> = React.createClass({ /* component code goes here */ });
export default <%= componentName %>;
```

When we copy the template file over and want to change the file name we would do the following for a specific file in the Yeoman `writeFiles` step:

```
// - `path` here is the node path module
// - `this` is the Yeoman generator context
// - `file` is the file being operated on in the `writeFiles` Yeoman generation step
var projectRoot = '/project/root/',
    fileName = path.relative(projectRoot, file),
    fileExt = path.extname(fileName),
    outputPath = path.dirname(fileName);

var outputFile = outputPath + '/' + this.componentName + fileExt;

// write the file
this.fs.copyTpl(
    this.templatePath(fileName),
    this.destinationPath(outputFile),
    { componentName: this.componentName }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation.